# CDOSYS error '80040213' - failed to connect to server

Tags: asp-classic

I have a Windows Server 2003 R2 running IIS and a website using classic ASP.
Trying to get it to use CDOSYS to email using our own (externally) hosted office365 exchange server.

I get the following error

```
CDO.Message.1 error '80040213'
The transport failed to connect to the server.
```

Which usually means one of 3 problems:
 1. Incorrect SMTP server / port
 2. Incorrect login/password
 3. FROM address not valid according to SMTP server (wrong domain)

The SMTP server and port are correct according to supplier.
The login/password is correct as I can log into the mail account using those details
The FROM address is correct as that is the account I am using to log in.

I can telnet to the exchange server from the web server on that address and port, so a connection can be made from the server at least.

So at the moment I'm at a loss as to what the problem might be.
Does anyone have any pointers as to anything else I need to look at?

This is the config the website is using

```
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2 
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.office365.com"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=587
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 20
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "username"
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I eventually got this solved.
I needed to use a different method of connecting to the office365 server.
So all is working as it should now.

Comment: Which method? Please elaborate better the answer so it can help others with the same problem!

Comment: Tell us what worked so it's useful to other people!

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup an SMTP relay in Office 365?

From the Office 365 Admin go to:

1. Admin > Exchange
2. Mail Flow > Connectors
3. Click add new SMTP relay connector
4. Select from "your organization's email server" to "office 365"
5. Give the connector a name and description
6. Select verify by IP address and add your web server IP
7. Save

Comment: the office365 setup is externally hosted and managed, so i don't have any control over it.

I was just given the details to use.

however, when you say ""your organization's email server" do you mean webserver? as we don't have an email server here, just a web server. the only email server we have is the office365 one.

Comment: @george-osullivan tried this and sadly made no difference, still same error

Answer (score 0):

Try `Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25`

With Office 365, cdo seems to prefer port 25, even when using authentication.

Here's a tried and tested configuration if it helps

```
Set iConfg = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Flds = iConfg.Fields
With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "myusername"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"
        .Update
End With
objMail.Configuration = iConfg
```

Comment: i'll try that tomorrow, but i'm sure i tried port 25 too which also didn't work.

Comment: just tried port 25 and got the same error i'm afraid @John

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpsendtls") = 1
```

instead of

```
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* this would help?

Comment: ironically with SSL and TLS and AUTOSTART TLS and other encryption methods, unless you actually know what is on the other end of the SMTP connection, I have found TLS instead of SSL to negotiate better in my connection test development. if success, you can look at the raw message on the recipient end and see if negotiation was successful and in what encryption.